# Jquery Json Post not sending data to controller

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4

i have this problem that's only occurring in this view and i don't know what is the reason. The jquery json posting is not sending any data to the controller as it's obvious upon debugging can you please help me.
this is the code

```
    $("#btConfirm").click(function () {
    //    alert(3);
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("EmployeeDetails", "User")",
            type: 'Post',
            data: {
                "empID": $("#empID").val(),alert:("sending"),
                "countryID": $("#dropDown1").val(),
                "genderID": $("#dropDown2").val(),
                "ParentAccountID": $("#dropDown3").val(),
                "accountTypeID": $("#dropDown9").val(),
                "countryCode": $("#countryCode").val(),
                "addressJudiciary": $("#addressJudiciary").val(),
                "addressProvince": $("#addressProvince").val(),
                "addressCity": $("#addressCity").val(),
                "addressStreet": $("#addressStreet").val(),
                "addressBuilding": $("#addressBuilding").val(),
                "addressFloor": $("#addressFloor").val(),
                "addressDescription": $("#addressDescription").val(),
                "addressPhone1": $("#addressPhone1").val(),
                "addressPhone2": $("#addressPhone2").val(),
                "addressEmail": $("#addressEmail").val(),
                "personFName": $("#personFName").val(),
                "personMidName": $("#personMidName").val(),
                "personFamName": $("#personFamName").val(),
                "personMotherName": $("#personMotherName").val(),
                "personFullName": $("#personFullName").val(),
                "personBirthDate": $("#personBirthDate").val(),
                "accountKind": $("#accountKind").val(),
                "accountNumber": $("#accountNumber").val(),
                "accountName": $("#accountName").val(),
                "accountNetAmount": $("#accountNetAmount").val(),
                "empContractNumber": $("#empContractNumber").val(),
                "empIssueDate": $("#empIssueDate").val(),
                "empStartDate": $("#empStartDate").val(),
                "empEndDate": $("#empEndDate").val(),
                "empSalary": $("#empSalary").val(),
                "empHourRate": $("#empHourRate").val(),
                "empDamanNumber": $("#empDamanNumber").val(),
                "empDamanValue": $("#empDamanValue").val(),
                "empTransportation": $("#empTransportation").val()
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText);
            },
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
                location.reload();
            }
        });
```

and the code of the controller is

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult EmployeeDetails(string cl)
    {
        try
        {
            string countryID = Request["countryID"];
            string genderID = Request["genderID"];
            string id = Request["empID"];
            string accountTypeID = Request["accountTypeID"];
            string countryCode = Request["countryCode"];
            string addressJudiciary = Request["addressJudiciary"];
            string addressProvince = Request["addressProvince"];
            string addressCity = Request["addressCity"];
            string addressStreet = Request["addressStreet"];
            string addressBuilding = Request["addressBuilding"];
            string addressFloor = Request["addressFloor"];
            string addressDescription = Request["addressDescription"];
            string addressPhone1 = Request["addressPhone1"];
            string addressPhone2 = Request["addressPhone2"];

            string addressEmail = Request["addressEmail"];
            string personFName = Request["personFName"];
            string personMidName = Request["personMidName"];
            string personFamName = Request["personFamName"];
            string personMotherName = Request["personMotherName"];
            string personBirthDate = Request["personBirthDate"];
            string accountKind = Request["accountKind"];
            string accountNumber = Request["accountNumber"];
            string accountName = Request["accountName"];
            string accountNetAmount = Request["accountNetAmount"];

            string empContractNumber = Request["empContractNumber"];
            string empIssueDate = Request["empIssueDate"];
            string empStartDate = Request["empStartDate"];
            string empEndDate = Request["empEndDate"];
            string empSalary = Request["empSalary"];
            string empHourRate = Request["empHourRate"];
            string empDamanNumber = Request["empDamanNumber"];
            string empDamanValue = Request["empDamanValue"];
            string empTransportation = Request["empTransportation"];

            //inserting country entry
            tblCountry ct = new tblCountry();
            ct.NameLtr = countryID;
            ct.CountryDefault = int.Parse(countryCode);
            isms.tblCountries.Add(ct);
            isms.SaveChanges();

            //inserting address entry
            int cntryID = ct.ID;
            tblAddress add = new tblAddress();
            add.CountryID = cntryID;
            add.Judiciary = addressJudiciary;
            add.Province = addressProvince;
            add.City = addressCity;
            add.Village = null;
            add.Street = addressStreet;
            add.Building = addressBuilding;
            add.Floor = int.Parse(addressFloor);
            add.Description = addressDescription;
            add.Phone1 = addressPhone1;
            add.Phone2 = addressPhone2;
            add.Email = addressEmail;
            isms.tblAddresses.Add(add);
            isms.SaveChanges();

            //inserting person entry
            int addID = add.ID;
            tblPerson prs = new tblPerson();
            prs.Name = personFName;
            prs.MidName = personMidName;
            prs.MotherName = personMotherName;
            prs.FamilyName = personFamName;
            prs.FullName = personFName + " " + personMidName + " " + personFamName;
            prs.BirthDate = DateTime.Parse(personBirthDate);
            if (genderID == "1")
                prs.Salut = "Mr";
            else
                prs.Salut = "Mrs";
            prs.GenderID = int.Parse(genderID);
            prs.BirthPlaceID = addID;
            prs.AddressID = addID;
            prs.HealthStatusID = 1;
            prs.SocialStatusID = 1;
            prs.isDeleted = false;
            isms.tblPersons.Add(prs);
            isms.SaveChanges();

            //inserting Parent Entry
            tblParent prt = new tblParent();
            prt.FatherID = null;
            prt.MotherID = null;
            prt.ResponsibleID = 0;
            prt.ResponsibleType = 0;
            isms.tblParents.Add(prt);
            isms.SaveChanges();

            //inserting account entry
            int prtID = prt.ID;
            tblAccount acct = new tblAccount();
            acct.ParentAccountID = prtID;
            acct.kind = int.Parse(accountKind);
            acct.Number = accountNumber;
            acct.AccountType = int.Parse(accountTypeID);
            acct.NetAmount = double.Parse(accountNetAmount);
            acct.Name = accountName;
            isms.tblAccounts.Add(acct);
            isms.SaveChanges();

            //inserting employee entry
            int actID = acct.ID;
            int prsID = prs.ID;
            tblEmpoyee emp = new tblEmpoyee();
            emp.AccountID = actID;
            emp.PersonID = prsID;
            isms.tblEmpoyees.Add(emp);
            isms.SaveChanges();

            //inserting employeeContract entry
            int empID = emp.ID;
            tblEmpoyeeContract empC = new tblEmpoyeeContract();
            empC.EmployeeID = empID;
            empC.ContractNumber = empContractNumber;
            empC.IssueDate = DateTime.Parse(empIssueDate);
            empC.StartDate = DateTime.Parse(empStartDate);
            empC.EndDate = DateTime.Parse(empEndDate);
            empC.Salary = double.Parse(empSalary);
            empC.HourRate = double.Parse(empHourRate);
            empC.DhamanNumber = empDamanNumber;
            empC.DhamanValue = double.Parse(empDamanValue);
            empC.Transportation = double.Parse(empTransportation);
            isms.tblEmpoyeeContracts.Add(empC);
            isms.SaveChanges();

            return Json("Added");
        }
        catch
        {
            return Json("Error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seriously? Use `data: $('form').serialize();` (and rename you dropdowns to match your property names) and make the parameter in you POST method your model so everything is correctly bound and your can delete all that awful `string countryID = Request[...];` code

Comment: Is it correct that there is `alert:("sending"),` in your `data`? Are there any javascript errors in your console?

Comment: i was just seeing if it works, it didnt, so i removed it and the result is all the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give you very easy example to do your question ,

> PS:your problem is your class didn't have enough parameters to catch
>   all data from Ajax

**Front-End Code**

```
<script>
    //$("#btConfirm").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("aaa" )",
            type: 'Post',
            data: {
                a: "1111",
                b: "1111"
                },
            dataType: 'json',
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText);
            },
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    //})
    </script>
```

**Back-End Code**

```
public JsonResult aaa(string a, string b)
        {
            return Json(new {  });
        }
```

> PS: I will be using class to send data if I were you like as following

```
namespace WebApplication5.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

            return View();
        }

        public JsonResult aaa(string a, string b)
        {
            return Json(new {  });
        }

        public JsonResult aaa(SampleClass sc)
        {
            return Json(new { });
        }
    }


    public class SampleClass
    {
        public string a { get; set; }
        public string b { get; set; }
    }
}
```